The least common multiple of four numbers is equal to their sum
Problem: The greatest common divisor of four positive integers, not necessarily distinct, is
equal to 1. Their least common multiple is equal to their sum. Find the number of
possible values of the sum of these four numbers.
I had my own approach but I failed to get the final solution:

Let the 4 numbers be a,b,c,d with a+b+c+d=S and a>=b>=c>=d and at least one number is different to any other numbers. => S < 4a => lcm(a,b,c,d) = 2a or 3a


However, I don't know how to continue

I would appreciate any help, hint, approach or solution

The problem comes from IIMC 2018 Keystage 2 (EMIC), according to
https://chiuchang.org/imc/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/07/BIMC-2018_Keystage-2_Team-1.x17381.pdf,
problem 10 from the Team category


A good way to proceed is to recast the problem into a form where you know the sum beforehand — by setting up an equation with fractions.
Divide your equation by $S$ and note that since $a,b,c,d$ must be divisors if $S$, the divided addends must be reciprocals of natural numbers. Call these natural numbers $S/a=a', S/b=b',$ and similar notation for $c'$ and $d'$. Therefore
$\dfrac1{a'}+\dfrac1{b'}+\dfrac1{c'}+\dfrac1{d'}=1, a'\le b'\le c'\le d'$
Clearly the leading term must be at least $1/4$ but less than $1/1$, so $2\le a'\le4$. Suppose first that $a'=4$. Then
$4\le b'\le c'\le d',$
and evidently the only solution that will give a sum of $1$ is
$\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\dfrac14=1.$
Clearing fractions gives $1+1+1+1=4$, which is valid as an addition; but $4$ is not the lcm of the terms on the left. The problem comes from the fact that the divisors we had calculated, $a'=b'=c'=d'=4$, do not themselves have a gcd of $1$. We must have the divisors relatively prime in order to get solutions that actually work.
We drop $a'$ to $3$ so that
$\dfrac1{b'}+\dfrac1{c'}+\dfrac1{d'}=\dfrac23, 3\le b'\le c'\le d'.$
Then $1/b'$ has to be at least $2/9$ so $b'$ may be $3$ or $4$. With $b'=3$ we have
$\dfrac1{c'}+\dfrac1{d'}=\dfrac{c'+d'}{c'd'}=\dfrac13,$
and then
$c'd'-3c'-3d'=0.$
We now "complete the rectangle", so to speak, by adding a constant whose product with $c'd'$ equals the product of the middle terms. Then we can factor the left side. Thus we will add $9$:
$c'd'-3c'-3d'+9=(c'-3)(d'-3)=9.$
So $c'-3$ and $d'-3$ must be complementary divisors of $9$ and from that observation we get two solutions
$(a',b',c',d')=(3,3,4,12)$
$(a',b',c',d')=(3,3,6,6)$
Remembering what happened when we tried $a'=4$, we note that the second solution does not have the numbers relatively prime and so will not work. The first solution is no problem, and we have
$\dfrac13+\dfrac13+\dfrac14+\dfrac1{12}=1\implies4+4+3+1=12.$
Thus $12$ is one possible sum.
We still have the possibility $a'=3,b'=4$. In this case
$\dfrac1{c'}+\dfrac1{d'}=\dfrac{c'+d'}{c'd'}=\dfrac5{12}$
$5c'd'-12c'-12d'=0$
We note that the completing constant would be fractional; we need a whole number there. So multiply the last equation by $5$, and then
$25c'd'-60c'-60d'=0$
$25c'd'-60c'-60d'+144=(5c'-12)(5d'-12)=144.$
So $5c'-12$ and $5d'-12$ are complementary divisors of $144$ and must each be three more than a multiple of $5$ (why?). So only the pairs $3,48$ and $8,18$ will work and we derive the candidates
$(5c'-12)(5d'-12)=3×48\implies (a',b',c',d')=(3,4,3,12)$
$(5c'-12)(5d'-12)=8×18\implies (a',b',c',d')=(3,4,4,6)$
The first solution misses the sorting condition $b'<c'$ and just duplicates the one found earlier. The second candidate passes as a second solution with a sum of $12$:
$\dfrac13+\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\dfrac16=1\implies4+3+3+2=12.$
I will let the reader work out the remaining possible $a'$ value, $a'=2$, using the above cases for $a'=3$ as guides. We have more possibilities for $b'$, and thus will get additional possible values for the original sum $a+b+c+d$. I ended up with six more possible values; do readers agree?

Thanks @Ocar Lanzi. There are exactly 7 possible values:
(12=1+1+4+6=2+3+3+4=1+3+4+4),
(10=1+2+2+5),
(18=1+2+6+9),
(24=1+3+8+12),
(20=1+4+5+10),
(42=1+6+14+21),
(30=2+3+10+15)
